# Is @Deprecated annotation being processed by an AbstractProcessor?

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to find the logic that processes the `@Deprecated` annotation.

In Eclipse, opening the "type hierachy" (F4) only shows me my own AbstractProcessor implementations.

Does anyone know what the class processing the @Deprecated annotation is called?

PS. The `@Deprecated` annotation was an example. I am curious about the other "core" java language annotations as well.

**EDIT**: Having looked at [com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/tools/javac/processing/JavacProcessingEnvironment.java#JavacProcessingEnvironment.initPlatformAnnotations%28%29) (A good entry point is the method discoverAndRunProcs(...)) at GrepCode I believe that @dot_Sp0T is correct. I will therefor accept his answer as the correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the [Javadoc for @deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html)

```
@Documented
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR,FIELD,LOCAL_VARIABLE,METHOD,PACKAGE,PARAMETER,TYPE})
public @interface Deprecated

A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists. Compilers warn when a deprecated program element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code.

Since:

1.5

See  The Java™ Language Specification:

9.6.3.6 @Deprecated
```

From this Javadoc entry we learn that the annotation is still present at runtime, thus we can assume it not being processed in the declaring code.

The last line of the javadoc leads us to [this section of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.6)

```
9.6.4.6. @Deprecated

A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because a better alternative exists. 

A Java compiler must produce a deprecation warning when a type, method, field, or constructor whose declaration is annotated with @Deprecated is used (overridden, invoked, or referenced by name) in a construct which is explicitly or implicitly declared, unless: 

- The use is within an entity that is itself annotated with the annotation @Deprecated; or 
- The use is within an entity that is annotated to suppress the warning with the annotation @SuppressWarnings("deprecation"); or 
- The use and declaration are both within the same outermost class.     

Use of the @Deprecated annotation on a local variable declaration or on a parameter declaration has no effect. 

The only implicitly declared construct that can cause a deprecation warning is a container annotation (§9.7.5). Namely, if T is a repeatable annotation type and TC is its containing annotation type, and TC is deprecated, then repeating the @T annotation will cause a deprecation warning. The warning is due to the implicit @TC container annotation. It is strongly discouraged to deprecate a containing annotation type without deprecating the corresponding repeatable annotation type.
```

Thus, as far as I understand it, the `@deprecated` annotation is processed by the compiler itself (resp in case of using eclipse by eclipse's code analyzing utility..).
That is **if** the annotation is processed at all. As stated in the comments it is possible that a given compiler might not process this or any other *default* annotation (alas that might clash with the language spec).

Your best bet at finding the specific class that is processing this or another annotation is by searching the respective JVMs sources (if you get your hands on them) for references to the annotation and then analyzing the code yourself to determine if it really does process it.
A website that might help you here is [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/). The site features a collection of sources, a (more or less userfriendly) search utility to sift through them and (most importantly) proper syntax highlighting.

---

To expand on this matter: The best place to find information about the java built-in things is the [Java Language Specification (v8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/) (which is to big to cite here).

To find information specifically about java's built-in annotations you would go have a look at [the predefined annotation types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4):

```
9.6.4. Predefined Annotation Types 

Several annotation types are predefined in the libraries of the Java SE platform. Some of these predefined annotation types have special semantics. These semantics are specified in this section. This section does not provide a complete specification for the predefined annotations contained here in; that is the role of the appropriate API specifications. Only those semantics that require special behavior on the part of a Java compiler or Java Virtual Machine implementation are specified here.
```

Comment: "Thus, as far as I understand it, the @deprecated annotation is processed by the compiler itself"--this is what I'm talking about. Not every Java compiler may process `@Deprecated`, and Eclipse's incremental compiler is just one example that *does*. You haven't explained how to find the logic (e.g. bytecode or sourcecode) that processes `@Deprecated`.

Comment: @Samuel thanks for pointing that out, allow me to update my answer

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Thank you, that makes sense to me. If I understand you correctly, the Deprecated annotation is part of the Core Java API, which a Java compiler, per specification, is required to process. I will have a look at the compilers code, instead of the files in the rt.jar.

Comment: @Hervian as far as I understand it from reading the documentation and doing some superficial codesearches, yes; Are you going to do some bytecode searches? Also be aware that parts of the JVM (no matter which) will likely be written in native code

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to extend `AbstractProcessor` to process annotations. It's only a convenience implementation, and prior to Java 6 it doesn't exist. The problem with annotations is that anybody can process any annotation, and as you've correctly identified it's difficult to determine who is processing an annotation. Also it'll be difficult to distinguish between usage of the annotation to annotate things and the annotation processing.

I.e.

```
@Deprecated
void deprecatedMethod()
```

Will be difficult to distinguish from

```
void deprecatedProcessing() {
    if (xxx.getAnnotation(Deprecated.class)) {
        /// Do something
    }
}
```

Because if you look at the class from a binary perspective both have references `java.lang.Deprecated`. If you look at the source, it's a bit easier to determine that one is processing (note the lack of @ sign when refering to the class in reflection), but if you wanted to do an extensive search of all libraries you would need the source of all those libraries.

My answer is that there is no easy way to search code for annotation processing.